# How can I return an array in GraphQL if I don't know how many there are (PHP, rebing/graphql-laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, graphql

There is a JSON array:

```
[{
   "src":{
      "hd":"1.jpeg",
      "small":"2.jpeg"
   }},
{
   "src":{
      "hd":"1.jpeg",
      "small":"2.jpeg"
   }
}]
```

How do I get the list through GraphQL? I don't know how many elements there are.

I can get a one dimensional array with pictures:

```
$pictures = new ObjectType(
    [
        'name' => 'pictures',
        'fields' => [
            'small' => [
                'type' => Type::string(),
            ],
            'hd' => [
                'type' => Type::string(),
            ],
        ]
    ]
);

return [
    ......
    'image' => [
    'type' => $pictures,
    'is_relation' => false,
    'resolve' => function ($content) {
        return $content->image[0]; // I return one here, but I need a list
    },
],
......
```

But how can I get an array of pictures if I don't know how many there are? Maybe one picture, maybe 10.
Googled for half a day, found information that GraphQL can return only what is hardcoded... Is it so?

Comment: `Type::listOf` ... your data structure doesn't match to required response (`src` level) ... follow some tutorial

Comment: xadm, Thank you! Yes, I have read this code many times. It's simple, but somehow I thought in a different direction :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary to know the number of images.

It seems that you need to define the Type of the field images correctly.

GraphQL know custom types and primitives.

```
type Image{
  name: String!
  small: String!
}
```

Image is a custom type, String is a primitive or basic type.

What you are probabably missing is, that you can have a **list** of a certain type.

I don't know your GQL framework, but here is an example:

**Line 23**:

- https://github.com/rebing/graphql-laravel/blob/master/example/Query/UsersQuery.php

Look at `Type::listOf()`

So, what you will need to do:

- define an ObjectType for a **single** Image (your current $images type)
- And then have a field images in your schema defined as return type **list of image**

Then you can resolve with `return $content->image` instead of `return $content->image[0]`

Comment: Thank you very much!!! ))
I just had to add a Type::listOf($pictures).

I just started to study, so I stumbled on such nonsense. Thank you!

Comment: I remember having the same struggle as you back then... We've **all** been there.